# How to show a popup alert in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, sweetalert2

In my database i have a table called tasks and it has a column named file where files are stored. Now i want when a user click in the file he will show a pop-up message which ask either to download or view a file.

partially try like this

```
<a href="" id="popup">{{ $task->file }}
```

And i created a sweet-alert message for this like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $('popup').on('click', 'td.warning input', function () {
            Swal.fire({
                    title: "Wow!",
                    text: "Message!",
                    type: "success",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    cancelButtonText: "View",
                    confirmButtonText: 'Download!',
                },
                function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted!", "success");
                    } else {
                        swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
                    }
                });
          });
      });
    </script
```

Please help me to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Add some html code to the sweet alert, so you can show messages or images, something as i did here, you can see the documentation for more examples of what you can do:
https://sweetalert2.github.io/

```
<a href="" id="popup">{{ $task->file }}
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
          $('popup').on('click', 'td.warning input', function () {
            Swal.fire({
                    title: "Wow!",
                    text: "Message!",
                    type: "success",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    cancelButtonText: "View",
                    confirmButtonText: 'Download!',
                },
                function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted!", "success");
                    } else {
                        swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
                    }
                });
          });
      });
    </script>
```

Then you can add on sweet alert, some kind of messaging by adding on if and else swal's some of html code:

```
if (isConfirm) {
        swal(
        title:"Deleted!", 
        text: "Your imaginary file has been deleted!",
        type: "success",
        html: '<h1>Text here to download or to view</h1>'+
        '<p>show some more text or show image</p>'
        );
} else {
        swal(
        title:"Cancelled", 
        text: "Your imaginary file is safe :)", 
        type: "error",
        html: '<h1>Text here to download or to view</h1>'+
        '<p>show some more text or show image</p>'
);
}
```

Hope this works for you...